# UDK Tutorials for the Absolute Beginner

Tags: unreal-development-kit

I am currently interested in game developing. I know a little bit of C# and I am pretty fluent in Java and VB.NET. My friend told me the UDK is the best free game development software out there. I downloaded it and played around with it for a while.

Then, I began looking around for tutorials. I tried [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcJ3J2Yf_Wg) one, but the tutor was very fast and most of the stuff I couldn't get. The documentation and tutorial videos that udk.com presents are not much helpful because they expect you to have some previous background knowledge on game development.

So, what are some good UDK tutorials for the ABSOLUTE beginner. Keep in mind I know absolutely nothing about game developing except hitting the play button and moving around the environment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a look at these and they seem to be pretty good: [thenewboston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7AAgQHJWGc&list=PLFF967D7CA020E636)

Comment: If this was a contest, you, my friend, just won. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I tip my hat to you sir.

Comment: could you update the link?

Comment: Just noticed the website isn't really operational anymore. I've updated the link to point directly to the Youtube playlist (and channel)

Answer (score 2):

Try these: [1](http://udkc.info/index.php?title=Tutorials%3aBeginning_your_game) , [2](http://udk-tuts.blogspot.com/) , [3](http://www.youtube.com/user/UDKLearning/featured) , [4](http://www.chrisalbeluhn.com/3D_Tutorials.html).

Comment: 1: Meh.

2: That's for the game

3: That's for people who know what they're doing

4: Meh.

I'll see if anybody has anything better. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately Link #1 does not seem to be working with a MediaWiki exception

Comment: @JoethePerson you are right. The entire site http://udkc.info/ seems to be down. It was working a year back when the answer above was posted.

Answer (score 2):

I am hoping that you are looking for some video tutorials on udk, then you should watch the videos provided by 3dbuzz on this page.

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/VideoTutorials.html

On top of that you may find a lot of good stuff here too

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/WebHome.html

And as this is a site for developers, I think you may want to check out the Tutorials for unreal script by Allar

http://allarsblog.com/unreal-tutorials/

I think this is enough to get u started. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a very good book to learn unreal scripting

[Unreal Development Kit Game Programming with UnrealScript: Beginner's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849691924)